# Metadata of ffmpeg is undefined in electron app

Tags: javascript, ffmpeg, electron

I correctly installed ffmpeg I'm able to check it by writing `ffmpeg` in cmd which give me this result

[image: img]

Now in my electron app in my index.html I'm geting input from user and sending custom event to electron side of app which lays in index.js entry point

index.html

```
<script>
    const electron = require('electron');
    const { ipcRenderer } = electron;

    document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const { path } = document.querySelector('input').files[0];

        ipcRenderer.send('video:submit', path);
    });
</script>
```

and using ffmpeg.ffprobe I'm trying to get metadata of video updated to input in electron side like so:

```
const electron = require('electron');
const ffmpeg = require('fluent-ffmpeg');

const { app, BrowserWindow, ipcMain } = electron;

app.on('ready', () => {
    const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({});
    mainWindow.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/index.html`);
});

ipcMain.on('video:submit', (event, path) => {
    ffmpeg.ffprobe(path, (err, metadata) => {
        console.log(metadata);
        //console.log(metadata.format.duration);
    });
});
```

And it console that metadata is undefined, when I uncomment `console.log(metadata.format.duration)` it says

> typeError: cannot read property 
>   'format' of undefined

What I'm doing wrong?

---

So I set two new environment variables and now other error occure when I console.log(error):

```
{ Error: spawn C:\Users\Borys\Documents\videoinfo\ffmpeg\bin ENOENT
at exports._errnoException (util.js:1024:11)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:192:19)
at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:374:16)
at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
code: 'ENOENT',
errno: 'ENOENT',
syscall: 'spawn C:\\Users\\Borys\\Documents\\videoinfo\\ffmpeg\\bin',
path: 'C:\\Users\\Borys\\Documents\\videoinfo\\ffmpeg\\bin',
spawnargs:
[ '-show_streams',
 '-show_format',
 'C:\\Users\\Borys\\Documents\\portfolio\\img\\header_video.mp4' ] }`
```

( I had to paste it as code because it was saying that my post containt code that is not properly formatted)

Comment: At first glance I'd say you're getting some error (stored in `err`) which is the reason for `metadata` to be `undefined`. Try logging `err`.

Comment: Oh sure.. I have error Error: Cannot find ffprobe

Comment: The [documentation on fluent-ffmpeg](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fluent-ffmpeg) states that Windows users will have to add the ffmpeg executable to their `%PATH` variable. So you will either have to add it to `%PATH` or set the `%FFMPEG_PATH` and/or `%FFPROBE_PATH` environmental variables.

Comment: I did only specify %PATH% by using some cmd command

Comment: What values should %FFMPEG_PATH and %FFPROBE_PATH has?

Comment: I mean to which directories it shoud direct?

Comment: To the directory where ffmpeg and ffprobe were installed, but the documentation shows some other ways on how to set the binary paths manually in your Electron code.

Comment: I set those 2 new variables and now other error occure there pls take a look at edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright thanks to @Alexander Leithner and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24324231/an-error-happened-spawn-enoent-node-js-ffmpeg) I figured it out. So error was my environment variables which should be:

- FFMPEG_PATH with value of path to ffmeg.exe
- FFPROBE_PATH with value of path to ffprobe.exe
- PATH with value of C:.......\ffmpeg\bin

Comment: yeah, working with Electron in Windows can be a pain.